# Why were curly braces chosen for the format specifier?

Tags: c#, python, string-formatting, history, delimiter

#### Historical curiosity and feature design

There's another question, [Why was the percent sign (%) chosen as the format specifier for the printf family of functions?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159593/why-was-the-percent-sign-chosen-as-the-format-specifier-for-the-printf-famil) but the reason for the percent sign (and [it's extensions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)) are surely(?) lost in the mists of time.

Anyhow, both [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) use the Curly Brace syntax `{_}` instead of the older percent syntax `%_`.

Has any designer of these languages/features ever given a rationale for this?

More generally, is there any reason to use two different characters (`{` *and* `}`) vs. just one character for the format specifier? Is there a reason to delimit both sides of the format specifier, instead of just the left side?

Please not that this does *not* ask which is "better". That would be silly.

Comment: IIRC, Python borrowed the curly braces from Java's `MessageFormat`, while C# borrowed it from one of the two Win32 formatting APIs. If so, there's not much interesting to learn from either Python or C# here, you'd have to go back (at least) one more step…

Comment: Python also has a `%` format option (older) that also supports name mapping, so `%(name)s` and similar. By using braces you get to start and end a field with more complex formatting options, such as `{name_from_mapping.attribute[more_indexing]:>06x}` for accessing an attribute on a keyword argument value as a mapping or list, then formatting it as a hex number with *right*-padding with zeros.

Comment: I was wrong about Java; that isn't even listed as one of the antecedents in the PEP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is developed out in the open. Most big changes are documented in [PEPs](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0000/). So, the first place to look is the PEP archive. The PEP should have links to relevant mailing-list discussions and tracker issues.

Smaller changes, you may have to search through the python-ideas and python-dev mailing lists and/or the issue tracker… but make sure to check the relevant "What's New" in the docs, because sometimes there's a useful link there.

Anything that goes back into the mists of time (around the 2.1 era) may be discussed on Guido's [Python History](http://python-history.blogspot.com/) blog. And sometimes you can find useful information in the source.

Anyway, in this case, it's [PEP 3101](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) that you want, in particular the section on "Alternate Syntax", where the author (not the language inventor in this case, but Talin) discussed some of the choices, and references, pros, and cons for each.

Ultimately, it doesn't look like there was a particularly compelling reason for one choice over another; after surveying the prior art, and probably bikeshedding it for weeks on one of the mailing lists, this one won.

I think I can make a decent guess as to why: Perl and the shell and lots of other traditional *nix stuff uses `${}`, with the braces option. The `$` just looks ugly to any Python developer who's escaped from Perl—and, more importantly, it might wrongly imply that you could use the same format strings in both Python and Perl, or that this would give you automatic interpolation like Perl rather than explicit interpolation as Python does. If you drop the `$`, the braces obviously can't be optional anymore. And there you have it.

---

As for C#, there were two different formatting APIs in Win32, one `printf`-like and one based on braces, used for i18n message catalogs. The braces variant didn't allow format specifiers; you had to pass it `WCHAR*` strings. The `printf`-like variant didn't allow ordering specifiers; you had to pass all the arguments in order (which really sucks when you're trying to internationalize your messages, because it's often hard to write a translate a sentence in a way that all the arguments appear in the same place). .NET sort of merged the best of the two.

Comment: [This](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-April/000368.html) looks to be the first suggestion of `{}` for Python: *'It seems to me that something like `"User {user} has printed {n} pages"` sets off the parameters from the rest of the
string more readably than `"User $user has printed $n pages"`'*. No source for that format quoted, though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Well, if the answer comes down to "because Greg Ewing has amazing instincts for taste and readability that even he can't explain", I wouldn't be particularly surprised by that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about C#, but in Python you can put formatting information inside of the braces. This makes it impossible to read if there isn't some sort of end character.

```
'The {:4.2f}th number.'.format(3.52352)
'The %4.2fth number.'.format(3.52352)
```

Or imagine dynamic formats without some ending.

```
format = '4.2f'
'Number: {1:{0}}.'.format(format, 3.2524)
```

It allows for a lot more flexibility and functionality.

Comment: Note that your `%` example is a perfectly valid printf specifier. It is harder to read, I agree, but it's valid, and not impossible once you get used to it.

Comment: The nesting example is nice though. That really works way better than when using just a single delimiter.